# Как затранскрибировать словосочетание «с жаром»?

Tags: фонетика

Как затранскрибировать словосочетание ***с жаром***?

Answer (score 1):

Сочетания сж-зж на стыке предлога и следующего слова произносятся как двойной твёрдый согласный Ж . Это не Ш, а именно Ж - перед звонким Ж С переходит в З, а потом в сочетании превращается в долгий согласный.

Comment: Мне неправильно кажется, что если внутри фразы произносишь, то получается именно ЖЖ, как Вы говорите, а если отдельно, то ШЖ? Удалю свой ответ, всё равно он хуже.

Comment: Как ставить долготу на этом сайте - не знаю,некоторые учебники вместо знака долготы ставят после согласного двоеточие, в Ворде я просто копирую готовое и ставлю. Здесь не получается. В печатном тексте можно рукой начертить, а здесь, выходит, только с помощью двоеточия:[ж: аръм]

Comment: Понятно. А на последний вопрос-то Вы ответите?

Comment: Не поняла, на какой вопрос? Как отдельно произносится? Но ведь "с жаром" - одно фонетическое слово . Это самостоятельное слово вместе с примыкающими к нему служебными словами, не имеющими собственного ударения, . Для удобства понимания таких сочетаний в транскрипции иногда используют знак "дефис": [на-ст`ол], [нъ-стал'`е]. Иногда ударение переходит на служебное слово - например, на предлог - тогда все гласные полнозначного слова подчиняются законам редукции, как и в любом фонетическом слове: без толку [б`ес-тълку].

Comment: http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-034.htm    
•  Сочетания еж - зж, сш - зш на стыке морфем, а также предлога и следующего слова произносятся как двойной твердый согласный : сжал, без жира, сшил, без шины, несший, влезший - [ж: ал], [б'иеж: ыръ], [ ш:ыл], [б'ие ш: ыны], [н'о ш: ый ], [вл'е ш: ый ].

Comment: Всё понял, спасибо большое за объяснения!